# Time only pickers for .NET WinForms?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, time

There are tons of good date pickers out there for Windows forms, but I have yet to find any good time only pickers.

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT**

I guess I should be more clear. I am talking about a nicer looking time picker. We use a commercial control suite, and the default time picker looks out of place because it is so plain.

Comment: The DateTimePicker in Windows Forms can do time-only with the CustomFormat property... are you just looking for a more sexy control?

Comment: Yes, something that looks nicer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

DatePicker has a property Format that can be set to Time.
Be sure to set ShowUpDown to True.

Infragistics is pretty popular for Winforms and has the option for its DateTimePicker.

> ... setting the MaskInput to {time} should
>   get the behavior you are looking for. 
>   If you only set the FormatString
>   property, the the time will display
>   only when the control is in edit mode
>   (when the cursor is in the control).

from http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/4172.aspx

Answer (score 21):

You mean, as opposed to the standard Winforms DateTimePicker?

```
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "hh:mm tt";
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
this.dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

...

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Use "hh:mm tt" to add AM/PM to the time.

Comment: @Michael: yep, and your suggested edit was right, edited. By the way, really dig KATG, hope you keep helping out.

Comment: Spotted! =D My pleasure. Thanks for providing the initial code. Saved me a lot of trouble. I'll pass along the praise to Keith and Chemda when I see them tonight.

Answer (score 8):

Just to elaborate on [Michael Petrotta's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23897/michael-petrotta) response the code

```
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "hh:mm";
```

is for the 12 hour format, where as the code below is for the 24 hr format

```
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm";
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Add a DateTimePicker control
2. Set the property 'Format' to 'Time'
3. Set the property 'Custom Format' to 'hh:mm:ss'
4. Set the property 'ShowUpDown' to 'True'

That's it

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to an open source time-picker on sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/time-picker/

[image: C# Winforms TimePicker]

**USAGE:** If you like to add TimePicker to your project, you can copy paste Opulos folder (Inside Zip file in the link) to your own project folder.

If you like to use it in toolbox you can modify `TimePicker` class and add a default constructor as

```
public TimePicker() :this(3, true, true, true, true) {

}
```

Afterwards you can drag and drop the custom timepicker from Toolbox to your own project.

Comment: Could you please guide us how we can add this to our project, for beginners like me?

Comment: @MericOzcan A new zip file has been added on sourceforge `v2022.11.03`. Open the sln file and click the build/start button, it should compile and run. The `TimePickerMillisPanel` class has an example how to add a `TimePicker` to a panel.

Answer (score 3):

Has been years of this thread but i modified the  open source time-picker on sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/time-picker/
to make a dll, just drag from explorer and drop to toolbox and you are ready to go

visual studio solution:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rfV8CXoyUxPuOHQK9dYcZj5WSCSF5gIz/view?usp=sharing

on debug folder is the dll