# Looking for time picker control with half hourly up/down

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am looking for a solution to a time picker which allows me to select the following:

```
00:30  > 01:00  > 01:30
```

When it reaches 23:30 it needs to wrap around to 0:00.

In other words I need to increment a half hourly period by selecting up or down.  I have tried incorporating a `hscroll` bar and amending a `timepicker` but this is quite sensitive and un-necessary in my view as I suspect there must be an easier way?

Any suggestions would be excellent.

Comment: Perhaps you can find something for the UI framework you're using. What is that, WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, MVC/Razor? - Edit: wow, 4 upvotes for this question. Why? I see almost zero research. There's tons of UI frameworks out there. Take a look at [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/editors-timepicker-overview.html), or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046268/time-only-pickers-for-net-winforms).

Comment: First thing that popped into my head was Enumerable.Range, but I would be interested to see what the end solution actually looks like.

Comment: Sorry @CodeCaster see edit

Comment: Well that's interesting. It's off the topic but I think the system is generating schedules.

Comment: There is no way to set an increment on a timepicker and use custom format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just sub-classed a `DomainUpDown` control to do this, here's the code:

```
class TimePicker : DomainUpDown
{
    public TimePicker()
    {         
        // build the list of times, in reverse order because the up/down buttons go the other way
        for (double time = 23.5; time >= 0; time -= 0.5)
        {
            int hour = (int)time; // cast to an int, we only get the whole number which is what we want
            int minutes = (int)((time - hour) * 60); // subtract the hour from the time variable to get the remainder of the hour, then multiply by 60 as .5 * 60 = 30 and 0 * 60 = 0

            this.Items.Add(hour.ToString("00") + ":" + minutes.ToString("00")); // format the hour and minutes to always have two digits and concatenate them together with the colon between them, then add to the Items collection
        }

        this.SelectedIndex = Items.IndexOf("09:00"); // select a default time

        this.Wrap = true; // this enables the picker to go to the first or last item if it is at the end of the list (i.e. if the user gets to 23:30 it wraps back around to 00:00 and vice versa)
    }
}
```

Add the control to your form like so:

```
TimePicker picker1;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    picker1 = new TimePicker();
    picker1.Name = "timePicker";
    picker1.Location = new Point(10, 10);

    Controls.Add(picker1);
}
```

Then when we want to get the selected time (I use a button here), we simply use the `SelectedItem` property:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(picker1.SelectedItem.ToString()); // will show "09:00" when 09:00 is selected in the picker
}
```

Documentation for `DomainUpDown`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.domainupdown.aspx

Comment: +1 `for` loop is a bit of an eye sore but good implementation.

Comment: Bug on this line this.SelectedIndex = times.IndexOf("09:00")

Comment: Sorry, I took the `List<string>` out but missed a line and didn't test. I've edited and tested this time, it all works =]

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in the past was built a list (2 columns) and bound to the combobox.  The first columns was just a string representing the time... the second was a double value corresponding to it.  Then, the combboox, I would have the DISPLAY value based on the time representation, but the ACTUAL value based on the double value...

ex:

```
Display    Actual
00:00   =  0.0
00:30   =  0.5
01:00   =  1.0
....
12:30   =  12.5
13:00   =  13.0
etc.
```

It's been some time since that, but could be generated via a simple loop in increments of .5 going 0 to 23.50 (23:30 night)

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to use a user control with a ListBox with integral height set to one item and a separate vertical scrollbar that is placed on top of the integrated listbox scrollbar.

Fill the ListBox with possible values, e.g. `00:00` to `23:30`.

In the Scroll event of the scrollbar use the comparison of `e.OldValue` and `e.NewValue` to increment or decrement the `TopIndex` property of the ListBox, so that the appropiate item is shown and it appears to be scrolling up or down.

You could then check if the first or last item is being shown, but since the scrollbar won't register a scroll in that event, you should move one or more items past the first or last item so it appears to keep wrapping around and the scollbar is always active and raises its Scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do a simple solution where you have one date-time picker that only picks the date and next to it a ComboBox which have the times 00.00, 00.30 ... 23.00, 23.30. I am looking into a solution where the date picker will have the exact feature you are looking for. Will edit this post if I find anything better.

## EDIT:

Not sure which versions of .net that have the NumericUpDown component but if you do have it you can use the value changed event with it. Here is some example code:

```
    decimal previousValue = 0;
    DateTime time = new DateTime(2000, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0);
    bool justChanged = false;
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (justChanged)
        {
            justChanged = !justChanged;
            return;
        }
        else
            justChanged = !justChanged;

        if (numericUpDown1.Value < previousValue)
            time = time.AddMinutes(-30);
        else
            time = time.AddMinutes(30);

        numericUpDown1.Value = decimal.Parse(time.ToString("HH,mm"));

        previousValue = numericUpDown1.Value;
    }
```

Comment: I do not need the date in this instance, only the time.  I could use a drop down, will see what comes up.  Thanks