# Adding external Folder from another Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, import

I am probably facing a basic problem. I would like to create TimePickers as in this project link: [TimePickerProject](https://sourceforge.net/projects/time-picker/)

This project was given as reference in one of the Stack overflow answers [Stack OverflowAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32057537/5384988)

You can download and directly run that project really easy. But couldn't add it to my own project as an independent TimerPicker Object. TimePicker class is inside Opulos folder. As you can see Opulos folder is copy pasted to my own project.

I [image]

And I can see that Timepicker inside my toolbox.

[image]

But when I try to drag it to my panel I am facing with this error.

[image]

Comment: Add an empty Constructor that calls the parametrized Constructor of the main class, e.g.,`public TimePicker() :this(3, true, true, true, true) { }` (i.e., pass default values or configure it to generate a different pre-defined behavior when the class is created via ToolBox) -- I gave the class a quick look: it's built for .Net Framework and includes some very old paradigms. Some more recent additions are quite good though (fortunately, disposable object are treated as such)

Comment: Thank you @Jimi giving a default constructor with out any argument worked.

Comment: Keep in mind that those classes are **not** built with the ToolBox in mind (no reference to ToolBox behavior is specified anywhere), it looks like all are meant to be instantiated in code. I.e., you may have the same problem somewhere else. You should know what to do (though decorating the public Control classes with appropriate `[ToolboxItem]`, `[ToolboxBitmap]` etc. stuff should be considered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain this process more clearly:

Just paste the [`Opulos folder`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/time-picker/) into the root directory of your program. (I am here. Net framework 4.8 winform)

[image]

Edit `Opulos/Core/UI/TimePicker.cs`

[image]

Add the below codes:

```
public TimePicker() :this(3, true, true, true, true) {

}
```

[image]

Then rebuild the program, you could find it in the toolbox.

[image]

Output：

[image]

Thanks to jimi's explanation:

> Pass default values or configure it to generate a different pre-defined behavior when the class is created via ToolBox.
>
> Keep in mind that those classes are not built with the ToolBox in mind (no reference to ToolBox behavior is specified anywhere), it looks like all are meant to be instantiated in code.
>
> I.e., you may have the same problem somewhere else.
>
> You should know what to do (though decorating the public Control classes with appropriate [ToolboxItem], [ToolboxBitmap] etc. stuff should be considered)

Comment: Hi Jiale, this is the correct answer indeed. But I am confused since @Jimi already give an answer in the comments :)

Comment: yes, thank for jimi's explanation. I edited the answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: Ok, I did you can also upvote my question if u like :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to drag another folder into your solution folder, then you can use the default windows file explorer. If you want to import a library from another project, simply right click Dependencies->add project reference, browse, and select the library. In general, you should avoid copying the code itself, and instead add a reference to the output.

Hope I could help, if I misunderstood your question I apologize!

Comment: I am not trying to add a project reference, what you mean? I am adding several classes. Not trying to add a full project? Try it for yourself, my problem can be easily created, if you have an open winform project.

Comment: @MericOzcan Yeah, if you are trying to copy a class from another folder, you can do that in the windows explorer. I am just saying that I don’t recommend copying a script, and instead copying the built assembly, unless you plan on editing the files independently of the original.

Comment: Hmm.. But in that case I would have many unnecessary things coming with the external project, no?

Comment: Yes, but it is much cleaner. What many developers do is put all classes/code they commonly use into one library, and update that. Every developer has a different way of solving problems, and you will probably finding yourself copying code a lot if you don’t do this. Plus, because dotnet uses JIT compilation, there is no memory usage for functions that are never called.

Comment: I would prefer, putting classes only. Btw, I could be able create timePicker inside my project. However in that project it was given as an example code inside a Panel class. In other words when I copy that panel class with a timePicker, I need to handle a panel. I am just missing something and I want to it clean, proper way.

Comment: @MericOzcan Not exactly sure what you mean, but as I said, if you want to copy a class without using a library, you can use windows explorer or notepad+visual studio to copy and paste. I don’t know of a way to have a c# file update itself from a reference. That is what libraries are for.